# How to render an Angular view when the model is changed by events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, model

I need to hide the 'Visible block' when pressing the button, but a moment later reappeared, without pressing the button. This version does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <div ng-show="isShow">Visible block</div>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.change()">Hide Block</button>
</body>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.isShow = true;

        this.change = function() {
            $scope.isShow = false;
            setTimeout(function() {
                $scope.isShow = true;
            }, 1000)
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Use $timeout instead of setTimeout

Comment: Thanks! It works with the $timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Angular's `$timeout` instead of the usual `setTimeout`, like so:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.isShow = true;
}, 1000)
```

This is because `setTimeout` works outside of the `$digest`; Angular's wrapper solves this.